# Dotted dash vertical line with gradient color

Tags: android

I want to make dotted line vertically with the gradient color effect. But I'm unable to do that. How can I approach. I am using this code on drawable for the dotted line

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="-5px"
    android:top="-5px"
    android:bottom="-5px">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke
            android:width="4px"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:dashGap="20px"
            android:dashWidth="20px" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Anyone knows please help
       Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a drawable like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item

        android:bottom="-5px"
        android:left="3px"
        android:right="-5px"
        android:top="-5px">
        <shape>

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#00ff00"
                android:endColor="#ff0000"
                android:startColor="#0000ff"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#fff"
                android:dashWidth="8dp"
                android:dashGap="16dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

now in layout you need to use a view and set this shape as background to it.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_shape"/>
```

you might need to change widht settings as per your requirements. Here is what I got

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use shape Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#000000"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px"
       android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Yes this is right . But my question is little bit different.How can I add gradient color on that dashed line?